# Testing GWT application in firefox - how to prevent firefox to cache css

Tags: firefox, gwt, caching

I develop a [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) application and use mozilla firefox for testing. I am looking for a way to configure firefox to not cache css files of my application. Because it often happens that I forget to clean the firefox cache and work on my application with old css styles.

Is it possible to configure mozilla firefox to not cache css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Web Developer extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) in Firefox lets you disable all caching. This should work for CSS, as well. It'll also help prevent those "doh" moments when the app starts working after you clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can just go to `about:config` and set both `browser.cache.disk.enable` and `browser.cache.memory.enable` to false. It will prevent everything from being cached, not just CSS. (I assume that's what the Web Developer extension is doing)